# How can I expose more than 1 port with Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-network

So I have 3 ports that should be exposed to the machine's interface. Is it possible to do this with a Docker container?

Answer (score 1107, accepted):

To expose just one port, this is what you need to do:

```
docker run -p <host_port>:<container_port>
```

To expose multiple ports, simply provide multiple `-p` arguments:

```
docker run -p <host_port1>:<container_port1> -p <host_port2>:<container_port2>
```

Comment: Thanks! Found this in the docs here: http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#network-port-mapping-refresher where it says `Note: The -p flag can be used multiple times to configure multiple ports.`

Comment: Is there a way to specify the ports in a config file? For example using the option `--env-file` ?

Comment: @GiovanniBitliner I'm still pretty new to this, but I'm pretty sure you would define ports in a Dockerfile with [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports), then perform `docker run -P` (note the uppercase) which automatically exposes all ports defined with EXPOSE in the Dockerfile

Comment: Multiple ports can halting the init process under a systemd service file?

Comment: I think the correct term here is `publish` not `expose`.

Comment: @ChrisSeymore where do we run these commands? Do we run them inside the docker container?

Comment: Is it is possible to map multiple docker ports to 1 host port?

Comment: I tried exposing multiple ports using multiple `-p` flags but it only exposed one port (the last argument of -p). I am using Docker Desktop with Docker Engine v20.10.5

Answer (score 482):

#### Step1

In your `Dockerfile`, you can use the verb `EXPOSE` to expose multiple ports.
e.g.

```
EXPOSE 3000 80 443 22
```

#### Step2

You then would like to build an new image based on above `Dockerfile`.
e.g.

```
docker build -t foo:tag .
```

#### Step3

Then you can use the `-p` to map host port with the container port, as defined in above `EXPOSE` of `Dockerfile`.
e.g.

```
docker run -p 3001:3000 -p 23:22
```

In case you would like to expose a range of continuous ports, you can run docker like this:

```
docker run -it -p 7100-7120:7100-7120/tcp
```

Comment: EXPOSE is only documentation for the ports that are published and useful for linking only. A complete list of ports can be found using -P and they will be automatically mapped to an available port on the host.

Comment: Expose is not needed. Remove the first step or make it optional.

Answer (score 47):

if you use `docker-compose.yml`file:

```
services:
    varnish:
        ports:
            - 80
            - 6081
```

You can also specify the host/network port as `HOST/NETWORK_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT`

```
varnish:
    ports:
        - 81:80
        - 6081:6081
```

Comment: When you specify just one number (e.g. `80`, not `80:80`), `docker` maps the specified container port to a host port from the ephemeral range.

Answer (score 5):

Use this as an example:

```
docker create --name new_ubuntu -it -p 8080:8080 -p  15672:15672 -p 5432:5432   ubuntu:latest bash
```

look what you've created(and copy its CONTAINER ID xxxxx):

```
docker ps -a
```

now write the miracle maker word(start):

```
docker start xxxxx
```

good luck

Answer (score 5):

Only one point to add. you have the option to specify a **range of ports** to expose in the dockerfile and when running it:

on dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 8888-8898
```

Build image:

```
docker build -t <image_name>:<version> -f dockerfile .
```

When running the image:

```
docker run -it -p 8888-8898:8888-8898 -v C:\x\x\x:/app <image_name>:<version>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating a container from an image and like to expose multiple ports (not publish) you can use the following command:

```
docker create --name `container name` --expose 7000 --expose 7001 `image name`
```

Now, when you start this container using the `docker start` command, the configured ports above will be exposed.

Answer (score 1):

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g pm2

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 9200

CMD npm run start
```

it is not working for two ports