# JMX - remote management into docker-compose container - Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub

Tags: java, docker, jmx

I want to do REAL remote JMX management into a docker container running a Spring Boot application:

architecture sketch

[image]

I've read a lot of documentation and my understanding is that this should be the server-side configuration:

```
java \
    -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.0.2.15 \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8600 \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8601 \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
    -jar my-spring-boot-app.jar
```

The url to use in JVisualVM should be `service:jmx:rmi://10.0.2.15:8601/jndi/rmi://10.0.2.15:8600/jmxrmi`.

**BUT THIS FAILS** (*Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub*) within JVisualVM (started on machine 1) - this is the log output:

> Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub    at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:369)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl$ProxyClient.tryConnect(JmxModelImpl.java:549)
>   [catch] at
>   com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl$ProxyClient.connect(JmxModelImpl.java:486)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl.connect(JmxModelImpl.java:214)

**IT WORKS** if I change the server application configuration to `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.19.0.6` (I use a BRDIGE docker network ... therefore routing to `172.19.0.6` is possible). With this configuration I am able to do JMX monitoring if the JVisualVM is started on the Docker Host (machine 2). But this is NO REAL REMOTE management because routing to `172.19.0.6` is usually impossible.

---

**Some additional informations:**

Port 8600, 8601 are exposed and are shown as LISTEN:

`pfh@workbench ~/temp/ % netstat -taupen | grep 860 
tcp6    0      0 :::8600   :::*   LISTEN   0    254349      -
tcp6    0      0 :::8601   :::*   LISTEN   0    254334      -`

and `telnet 10.0.2.15 8600` from machine 1 is possible.

I get the same wrong behavior with Java `1.8.0_111` and `1.7.0_80` on docker containers and docker host (running JVisualVM).

BTW: this configuration works if the Spring Boot application is running on machine 2 directly (without Docker).

I know that JMX usually negotiates random ports ... I try to make them explicit in my configuration. There is also one additional property `-Dcom.sun.aas.jconsole.server.cbport=8602` that can be set but this did not solve the problem.

**Where is my fault?**

Comment: "Port 8600, 8601 are exposed" meaning you ran both `docker run -p 8600:8600 -p 8601:8601 somedockerimage` to have those ports on your host, as well as the docker image also `EXPOSE`s those ports internally (like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32806333/995891)?

Comment: exactly ... I don't know if it important but the containers are started/managed by `docker-compose` ... I will test if this changes something

Comment: @zapl: wow ... it works when doing it with `docker run` but not via `docker-compose up ` ... this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

`my-spring-boot-service:
      ...
      ports:
        - "8610:8610"
        - "8611:8611"`

Answer (score 1):

In my problem description I concealed the the docker container was started via `docker-compose`with this configuration:

`my-spring-boot-service:
      ...
      ports:
        - "8610:8610"
        - "8611:8611"`

... and this results in open ports which seem to be bound to all interfaces as you can see via `docker inspect my-spring-boot-app`:

`"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "ac1a27e2696fd4ac2fcddf6e0935716304e348203ddbe1a0f8e31114cc6e289b",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "8610/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "8610"
            }
        ],
        "8611/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "8611"
            }
        ],`

I cannot see a problem here ... **but this seems to be the problem** because if I start the container via `docker` itself (as suggested by @zapl)

`docker run -p 8610:8610 -p 8611:8611 my-spring-boot-app-image`

**IT WORKS - BUT NOT THE WAY I WANT - I want to use docker-compose**.

There is a difference between the two deployment ... `docker inspect network <foo>`.

... on the working `docker` network looks this way:

```
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
```

on the non-working `docker-compose` network looks this way:

```
    "Options": {},
```

Both container configurations use no explicit defined network but the default one.

**QUESTIONS:** Is there a configuration missing? Should I define a network explicitly in `docker-compose`?

`docker-elk` is a docker-compose based deployment. I configured the [described configuration of the JMX interface](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk#how-can-i-enable-a-remote-jmx-connection-to-logstash) and was able to remote JMX this machine.

My JMX configuration is exactly the same - MINE IS NOT WORKING :-(

---

OS/Arch: linux/amd64
docker version: 1.12.2
docker-compose version: 1.8.0, build f3628c7 and 1.9.0, build 2585387

Answer (score 1):

maybe I should switch to JMXMP instead of JMXRMI - https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleCoherence/docs/5.monitoring