# Publish several ports

Tags: docker

Docker command `docker container run --publish 8000:8080 --detach --name bb bulletinboard:1.0` publishes dockers `8080` port to `8000`. But how to deal when I need to publish two ports `8000:8080` and `1001:1010`?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate:
[How can I expose more than 1 port with Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845056/how-can-i-expose-more-than-1-port-with-docker)

`docker run -p <host_port1>:<container_port1> -p <host_port2>:<container_port2>`