# C# app runs fine on VM, but not on docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, http, port

Have a small ftp server with http in a app, which runs fine in a vm.

I'm trying to dockerize it, which when I do, works ok If I ssh in the container (I can telnet both localhost and the container VM), but I can't access from the machine.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["proj.csproj", "proj"]
RUN dotnet restore "proj/proj.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/proj"
RUN dotnet build "proj.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "proj.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
EXPOSE 21
EXPOSE 80
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=development
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "proj.dll", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:80"]
```

Docker inspect:

```
            "Ports": {
                "21/tcp": null,
                "80/tcp": null
```

PS: I changed the paths manually to not expose my project, so may have some mistakes with folders name

Comment: How do you start the docker container? `EXPOSE` just specifies that these ports should be exposed, it's the command that actually exposes them. So you need to do `docker run -p 80:80 -p 21:21`

Comment: Or `docker run -P` to publish all EXPOSEd ports

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I expose more than 1 port with Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845056/how-can-i-expose-more-than-1-port-with-docker)

Comment: I'm not looking for commands like docker run -P or -p 80:80. I need to fix my app or .net deploy to bind the ports correclty

Comment: Yes, that's what I've just told you how to do? Your, issue it appears anyway, is that you're not exposing the ports outside of the docker container. They need to be mapped