# Why can we have more time -p options in docker run command line

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-run

I have seen a docker run command line as following:

```
docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

This command launch the image rabbitmq:3-management
With the option --it, it runs in the interactive mode, so we can execute commands inside the container while it is still running.
With the option --name, it allow me to assign the rabbitmq name to my container.

What i dont understand is the -p option, why it is twice ?

I know that the only way to access the process is from inside of it. To allow external connections to the container, you have to open (publish) specific ports.

So it is working like: `docker run -p 8080:80 [image_name]`.
so it this command i to map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host.

So my question is why it is like this

```
-p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Why i have -p twice ?
Why i have the same port `5672:5672 and 15672:15672` ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this question help: [How can I expose more than 1 port with Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845056/how-can-i-expose-more-than-1-port-with-docker). I would better use the term "publish" though, not "expose".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ accepts TCP client connections (consumers, publishers) on port `5672` by default. So `-p 5672:5672` means "map port `5672` on the host to port `5672` of this container".

The RabbitMQ Management UI is an HTTP server which listens on port `15672` by default. So `-p 15672:15672` means "map port `15672` on the host to port `15672` of this container" so that you can access the management UI in a web browser like `localhost:15672`.

In both cases, the number on the *left* is the host port number. If `5672` was a port you were already using on your host, you could map a different port on your host to the container like `-p 95672:5672`.